# Is there any way to share a pts/x?

Tags: ssh, connection

What I mean is, user A connect via ssh to the box (ubuntu 12.04). Then ssh to another box (Linux/Solaris/etc) and work.
User B connects to ubuntu box and can see what user A is doing.

I know for solaris are utilities called ntd (to open a shared session) and ntio (to join to the previous opened session, you can have read or write access to the opened session).

Answer (score 4):

GNU `screen` can do session sharing with the the `multiuser` command and the `-x` flag (personally I've only tried this in single user mode, so some of the below is guesswork). From the manual page, I gather UserA would have to:

1. Run `screen`
2. ctrl-A
3. `:multiuser on`
4. ctrl-A
5. `:acladd UserB`

Then UserB would have to:

```
 screen -x UserA/
```

And from then on they would share the screen. Note that the manual page also says:

> This requires setuid-root.

So this may or may not work on any given server.

Comment: @Walter please express your gratitude by [marking Paul's answer as the accepted answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) rather than by commenting on it.

Comment: @Pilot6 I notice only now that this was asked 2 years ago and floated up due to your edit. I bet we won't see Walter coming back to do the proper thing. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think [byobu](https://www.byobu.org/) is a good tool for your requirement.